# Cannot redeclare sanitize() error

Tags: php

I have the following error in the nginx logs:

```
2011/12/16 13:52:30 [error] 7490#0: *1000 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare sanitize() (previously declared in /usr/share/www/includes/class_downloads.php:4) in 
    /usr/share/www/includes/class_downloads.php on line 17" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /aaf104/fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood-video22/index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.example.com"
```

All my sites are showing the same error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sanitize() (previously declared in 
/usr/share/www/includes/class_downloads.php:4) in 
/usr/share/www/includes/class_downloads.php on line 17
```

Configuration:

Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS, nginx/0.7.65, PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid (fpm-fcgi)

[nginx config](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17184781/down/nginx.conf)

[fastcgi config](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17184781/down/main.conf)

[site config](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17184781/down/site_config)

Could someone help me on this? I understand that you will not be checking all configs, etc. but I will be grateful for any hint to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is explicit.  You have a function "sanitize()" appearing more than once in your code. First on Line 4 of /usr/share/www/includes/class_downloads.php and then in Line 17 of the same file.

A PHP function can only appear once in a code stream.

Comment: The error has gone away when we disabled all plugins. It seems that a module is missed or there is another server configuration problem. Our server was restored from crash and it's quite difficult to retrieve its configuration now. Just to your reference, I have tried replacing all includes with include_once, etc. Thank you for reply and sorry that I can't vote for your post due to lack of reputation.

Comment: Glad the issue has been resolved. You can accept the answer by ticking the check mark if it did indeed answer your query.